# How to demonstrate a race condition in a HashMap?

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

I am teaching concurrent programming in Java and would like to demonstrate to the students the problems that can arise by using non-thread-safe data structures. I created the following program:

```
    Map<String,String> favoriteFoods = new HashMap<>();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
        favoriteFoods.put("Alice","avocado");
        favoriteFoods.put("Bob","banana");
    });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
        favoriteFoods.put("Alice","aloysia");
        favoriteFoods.put("Carl","candy");
    });
    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    System.out.println(favoriteFoods);
```

where a non-thread-safe HashMap is accessed from two different threads. However, the program works fine every time I run it.

How can I change the code in order to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Think more pathologically. Put loops in your anonymous `Thread` instances, and remove one, or both, of the `joins`...

Comment: This is really a [cseducators.se] question, and probably should be migrated there. Also, it sounds like that site might be of interest to you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add elements to HashMap with hash collisions:

```
import java.util.*;
public class HashMapRaceCondition2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        class MyClass {
            int value;

            MyClass(int value) {
                this.value = value;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object o) {
                if (this == o) return true;
                if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

                MyClass myClass = (MyClass) o;

                if (value != myClass.value) return false;

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                return 42;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "MyClass{" +
                        "value=" + value +
                        '}';
            }
        }  // MyClass

        Map<MyClass,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i =0; i < 1000; ++i) {
                map .put(new MyClass(i), i);
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 2000; i < 3000; ++i) {
                map.put(new MyClass(i), i);
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();

        System.out.println(map.size());
    }
}
```

This code fails on my machine once per 5-6 executions.

Comment: In what way does it fail?

Comment: Cool! I add 1000 items in each thread, and in almost every run, the total number of items is less than 2000! It becomes 2000 when I use ConcurrentHashMap, just as expected.

Comment: In fact, the demo works even with a plain Map<String,Integer>.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(1);

    IntStream.range(0, 100)
            .parallel()
            .map(x -> {
                map.put(x, x);
                return x;
            })
            .max();

    System.out.println(map.size());
```

Run it a few times and the result will not be `100` all the time

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, your very first code should demonstrate race condition without ANY further changes. I tried it several times and sometimes Alice 'IS' avocado and some other times Alice 'is' aloysia. I assume that your so-called correct answer (in this case Alisia maps only to avocado or only to aloysia) is due to super-fast, multi-core computers. You can ask if someone of your students can run your code in some older hardware.

Comment: The code demonstrates a race condition, but it doesn't demonstrate unsafety. The interesting cases -- the ones that really justify `synchronized` and `ConcurrentHashMap` and so on -- are cases where mappings completely disappear, or even where the `HashMap` gets completely corrupted.