# Java: Testing a Service for Concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

I have a service class containing a method to add a `Student` to a `Section`. Now each `Section` has a `set` of `Students` associated with it.

Also, there is a `Map<Section, Set<Student>>` defining the relationship between the two.

The `service` looks something like this with the `addStudent` method:

```
public class MembershipService {

private final Map<Section, Set<Student>> studentsBySection = new HashMap<>();


public void addStudentToSection(Student student, Section sec) {

 Set<Student> students = studentsBySection.get(sec);
    if (students == null) {
        students = new HashSet<>();
        studentsBySection.put(sec, students);
    }
    students.add(student);

}
//  ..... also containing helper method : getStudents(Section s)
```

I require to test the functionality in multithreaded scenario where I need to show what will happen if two or more threads try to add or read students from the common `map`.

I clearly know that replacing `Hashmap` with `ConcurrentHashMap` will solve my purpose but am not able to demonstrate the exact behaviour.

**My Solution**

I created two threads: `Student1` and `Student2` and tried passing the same `Service` instance to both and perform an add. Expected behaviour with `hashmap` should be `ConcurrentModificationException` and with `ConcurrentHashMap` it should not throw. But it is not showing the expected behaviour and working just fine even with `HashMap`. Please guide.

Here is the code:

**Student1**

```
public class Student1 implements Runnable{

Services services;

public Student1(Services ser) {
    this.services =  ser;
    new Thread(this, "Student 1").start();
}



@Override
public void run() {
    final Student ALEX = new Student("alex");


    services.getMembershipService().addStudentToSection(ALEX,services.getSection());;

    try {
        System.out.println("Student 1 sleeping");
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

}

**Student2**

```
  public class Student2 implements Runnable{

Services services;

public Student2(Services ser) {
    this.services =  ser;
    new Thread(this, "Student 2").start();
}



@Override
public void run() {
    final Student JOHN = new Student("john");


    services.getMembershipService().addStudentToSection(JOHN,services.getSection());;

    try {
        System.out.println("Student 2 sleeping");
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

}

**Tester.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Services services = ServiceFactory.createServices();
    final Section A = new Section("A");
    services.createSection(A);

    Student1 one = new Student1(services);
    Student2 two = new Student2(services);

}
```

How do I prove my case?

**NOTE:** This is not about `How ConcurrentHashMap works in java` or multithreading in general.Am aware of that. Am just not able to align it with my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

First, `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown only by iterators, not bu `put()/get()`

> The iterators returned by all of this class's "collection view
>   methods"  * are *fail-fast*: if the map is structurally modified
>   at any time after  * the iterator is created, in any way except
>   through the iterator's own  * remove method, the iterator
>   will throw a  * {@link ConcurrentModificationException}.  Thus, in the
>   face of concurrent  * modification, the iterator fails quickly and
>   cleanly, rather than risking  * arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior
>   at an undetermined time in the  * future.

Good way to show that `Hashmap` is this case is not thread-safe is to change your `Section` class to return constant from `hashCode()` method (to make failure faster).

Then you just create let's say 1000 of different `Section` objects and try to call your service to map students to section in several threads. Basically when you finish mapping students to sections then size on map will not match the number of sections, it will be less then number of different sections.

Comment: Creating 1000 different sections will probably be on the same bucket location because of constant hashcode. Not able to understand how will the mapping work in this case or how the size would be compared?

Comment: Bucket in `HashMap` is a kind of linked list. So when several threads will start to add elements to `HashMap` which will end up in the same bucket those elements will be added in a list which is not thread-safe. This hack with constant hash code will increase chance of incorrect behavior while adding elements in a `HashMap`. Basically in case of not thread-safe `HashMap` after adding several elements in several threads final size of map will be less than number of added elements

Comment: You can check answers to this question to get an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47586356/how-to-demonstrate-a-race-condition-in-a-hashmap/47586668#47586668

Comment: Wouldn't that be the case for ConcurrentHashMap too since hashcode is constant?

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` locks bucket for `put()` so it will work correctly though performance would be worse than with hashCode implementation that returns different values

Answer (score 0):

The reason your HashMap and ConcurrentHashMap working same in multithreaded environment is due to less input.
I am putting and reading 200 key value pair at same time.

Just replace ConcurrentHashMap to HashMap in the code you will get the concurrentModificationException.

**ConcurrentHashMap Implementation:**

```
package com.java.ConcurrentHashMap;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
public class ConcurrentHashMapDemo {


    private  final ConcurrentHashMap<Section,Set<Student>> studentsBySection = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public  void addStudentToSection(Student student, Section sec) {
//System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
         Set<Student> students = studentsBySection.get(sec);
            if (students == null) {
                students = new HashSet<>();
                studentsBySection.putIfAbsent(sec, students);
            }
            students.add(student);

        }




      public static void main(String[] args) {
          ConcurrentHashMapDemo ob = new ConcurrentHashMapDemo();



          Thread t1 = new Thread(ob.new WriteThreasOne());
          t1.setName("one");

          Thread t3 = new Thread(ob.new WriteThreasTwo());
          t3.setName("three");
          Thread t2= new Thread(ob.new ReadThread());
          t2.setName("two");
          t1.start();
          t2.start();
          t3.start();
      }
      class WriteThreasOne implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            final Section A = new Section("A");

            for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
                addStudentToSection(new Student("alex"+i),A);
            }




        }
      }
      class WriteThreasTwo implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            final Section A = new Section("A");
            for(int i=1;i<100;i++) {
                addStudentToSection(new Student("sam"+i),A);
            }


        }
      }  
      class ReadThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

           Iterator<Section> ite = studentsBySection.keySet().iterator();
           while(ite.hasNext()){
               Section key = ite.next();
               System.out.println(key+" : " + studentsBySection.get(key));
          }
        }
      }   
}
```

**Section Class:**

```
package com.java.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class Section {

    public Section(String sectionName) {
        this.sectionName = sectionName;
    }

    private String sectionName;



    public String getSectionName() {
        return sectionName;
    }

    public void setSectionName(String sectionName) {
        this.sectionName = sectionName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Section [sectionName=" + sectionName + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((sectionName == null) ? 0 : sectionName.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Section other = (Section) obj;
        if (sectionName == null) {
            if (other.sectionName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!sectionName.equals(other.sectionName))
            return false;
        return true;
    }



}
```

**Student Class:**

```
package com.java.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class Student {



    private String studName;

    public Student(String studName) {

        this.studName = studName;
    }

    public String getStudName() {
        return studName;
    }

    public void setStudName(String studName) {
        this.studName = studName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [ studName=" + studName + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: I have change the code according to your need, now you will get how HashMap v/s ConcurrentHashMap works in multithreaded environment.